# I have 2 pages with 2 buttons, each button loads content within a div

Tags: php, html

I have a page called admin.php. It has 2 buttons on the left, one view records and another creates a record. When the buttons are clicked it loads up the content into a div on the right. It works OK with the view records button, but when I click the create record it loads up behind the view records content.

A bit hard to describe so I have created two PhpFiddle pages to demonstrate.

Here is the admin page:  http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/9vgr-dn34

Here is the create record page:  http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/bvan-3wph

Comment: I only see 2 errors: 1. the html tag `</html>>`; 2. you don't have an `exit` after the `header('location:admin-log.php');`, I could go in your admin without requiring a username or password.

Comment: Thanks, this doesn't solve my problem though.. @machineaddict

Comment: I added the exit; after the $_POST['createRecord'] part of the code and it has worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if createRecord is clicked then run admin-create.php

```
if(isset($_POST['createRecord'])) {
include ('admin-create.php');
```

without the next line the admin-create content will be loaded behind the view-records content

```
exit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a form to submit the users actions you should use a GET variable.

The link could be:

```
<a href="admin/?page=PAGE1">Get Page 1 Content</a>
```

You can then grab the variable by using this code

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['page'])) {
   if($_GET['page'] == "PAGE1") { // It's page one so load that page
      include('includes/page1.php');
   } else {
      // Load the other pages
   }
} else {
   // No page selected: Load the default page
   include('includes/default.php');
}
```

Edit: Even better still add multiple pages and include the header and footer.